# What properties to use in Lable so that the text does not go outside the window

Tags: python, kivy

I have a problem that I don't know what command to use to prevent text from going outside the window

```
    Label:
        color: (0,1,0,1)
        size_hint: (None,None)
        pos_hint: {'y': 0.75, 'x': 0.2}
        center: self.center

    Button:
        text: "Powrót"
        font_size: 32
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5}
        size_hint: (1, 0.1)
        on_release: app.root.current = "first"
```

Thank you in advance for any advice

Comment: Try setting `text_size` to the size of your label.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#sizing-and-text-content). Try adding:

```
size: self.texture_size
```

to the `Label`.